# Different ways of notation for jQuery on() handlers including namespacing

Tags: jquery, namespaces, onclick, notation

When I apply on()-handlers I prefer the following notation if I have more than one to apply:

```
$(window).on({
    keyup: function (e) {
        applyKeyEvents(e, modal);
    },
    click: function (e) {
        applyMouseEvents(e, modal);
}
```

Does anybody knows how to set a namespace within this notation?

I solved the problem in this case with falling back to a single notation:

```
$(window).on('click.modalClickClose', function (e) {
    applyMouseEvents(e, modal);
});

$(window).on('keyup.modalKeyClose', function (e) {
    applyKeyEvents(e, modal);
});
```

But I really hate to repeat myself. Same issue/question for using the off()-method with more than one handler.

This works:

```
$(window).off('click.modalClickClose');
$(window).off('keyup.modalKeyClose');
```

I bet the off()-thing is a easy one, but I don't get it after coding the last 15 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing an object to `.on()` to list more than one event you can (as with any JavaScript object literal) put the property names in quotes if you need the property names to include a dot:

```
$(window).on({
    "keyup.modalKeyClose" : function (e) {
        applyKeyEvents(e, modal);
    },
    "click.modalClickClose" : function (e) {
        applyMouseEvents(e, modal);
    }
});
```

According to the [`.off()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/) you can remove multiple handlers with one call by listing all the handlers in the same string, with or without namespaces:

```
$(window).off("keyup.modalKeyClose click.modalClickClose");
```

Note that if you were to give both of your events the same namespace:

```
$(window).on({
    "keyup.modalClose" : function (e) {
        applyKeyEvents(e, modal);
    },
    "click.modalClose" : function (e) {
        applyMouseEvents(e, modal);
    }
});
```

...then you could remove them by specifying just the namespace:

```
$(window).off(".modalClose");
```

Comment: Thx, I knew the off thing is that easy, tried everything except without comma. Great hint with just one namespace, exactly what I needed. I am exploring namespaces for the first time. Thx for your time and help.